# is this the right way to do a sequence?

Tags: java

i need to do a secuence of "1,-1,2,-2,3,-3..." for n numbers, i already make the code, and it works, but i dont know if this is the correct way to do it

```java
      Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Ingresa el numero N");

      int n = teclado.nextInt();
      int r = 0;

      for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

          if (i >= 0) {
              r = i * 1;
          }
          if (r >= 0) {
              r = i * -1;
          }

          System.out.print(i+","+r+",");
      }
```

Comment: If it works, it's correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions abour working code belong on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may improve upon your current code by just using a single counter and loop:

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Ingresa el numero N");
int n = teclado.nextInt();

for (int i=1; i <= n; ++i) {
    if (i > 1) System.out.print(",");
    System.out.print(i + "," + (-i));
}
```

This prints, for `n=3`:

```
1,-1,2,-2,3,-3
```